# Трудности с созданием программы, использующая MenuBar и CentralWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qmainwindow, menubar

Есть два класса, первый строит "скелет" окна и задает ему параметры, а второй строит различные формы на окне первого класса. Так вот, у первого класса есть зона только 'Central Widget', а мне необходимо построить меню сверху(то-есть использовать MenuBar) и остальное пространство под Central Widget.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал создавать еще один виджет для Menu Bar и устанавливать меню с помощью функции `SetMenuBar()`

```
self.barMenu = QWidget()
self.setMenuBar(self.barMenu)
```

но этот код не работает. Ниже прилагаю полный код, использующий только `central widget`. Здесь всё тоже без странностей, выравнивание всех виджетов происходит не полносью вверху, хотя использую `Qt.AlignTop`)приложу фото с неправильным расположением виджетов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.label = QLabel()
        font = QFont('Arial', 20, QFont.Bold)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.start = QPushButton("Start")
        #self.start.clicked.connect(self.startTime)

        self.pause = QPushButton("Pause")
        #self.pause.clicked.connect(self.pauseTime)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.start)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.pause)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)


class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignBaseline | Qt.AlignTop)

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PS большой отступ сверху у виджетов
[image: большой отступ сверху]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я добавил все необходимое для решения вашего вопроса:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QMenuBar, QMenu, QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont,  QWindow,  QKeySequence


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.label = QLabel()
        font = QFont('Arial', 20, QFont.Bold)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.start = QPushButton("Start")
        #self.start.clicked.connect(self.startTime)
        self.pause = QPushButton("Pause")
        #self.pause.clicked.connect(self.pauseTime)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.start)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.pause)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)


class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

        self.label = QLabel("Hello, World")                                    # +++
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self._createActions()                                                  # +++
        self._createMenuBar()                                                  # +++
        self._connectActions()                                                 # +++

        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignBaseline | Qt.AlignTop)

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def _createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("&New")
        self.newAction.setIcon(QIcon("img/new.png"))
        self.newAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")

        newTip = "Create a new file"
        self.newAction.setStatusTip(newTip)
        self.newAction.setToolTip(newTip)        
        self.openAction = QAction(QIcon("img/open.png"), "&Open...", self)
        self.openAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.saveAction = QAction(QIcon("img/save.png"), "&Save", self)
        self.saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon("img/exit.png"), "&Quit", self)    
        
        self.copyAction = QAction(QIcon("img/copy.png"), "&Copy", self)
        self.copyAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Copy)
        self.pasteAction = QAction(QIcon("img/paste.png"), "&Paste", self)
        self.pasteAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Paste)
        self.cutAction = QAction(QIcon("img/cut.png"), "C&ut", self)
        self.cutAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Cut)
        
        self.helpContentAction = QAction(QIcon("img/readMe.png"), "&Help Content", self)
        self.aboutAction = QAction("&About", self)

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        # или так:
        # menuBar = QMenuBar(self)
        # self.setMenuBar(menuBar)    

        # Создание меню с использованием объекта QMenu
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)     
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)  
      
        # Adding an Open Recent submenu
        self.openRecentMenu = fileMenu.addMenu("Open Recent")
      
        fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAction)
        fileMenu.addSeparator()                              
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        
        # Создание меню с использованием заголовка
        editMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        editMenu.addAction(self.copyAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAction)
        editMenu.addAction(self.cutAction)
        editMenu.addSeparator()                                     
        
        # Используя icon and title
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu(QIcon("img/qtlogo.png"), "&Help")
        helpMenu.addAction(self.helpContentAction)
        helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAction)

    def _connectActions(self):
        # Connect File actions
        self.newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.saveAction.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)    
        
        # Connect Edit actions
        self.copyAction.triggered.connect(self.copyContent)
        self.pasteAction.triggered.connect(self.pasteContent)
        self.cutAction.triggered.connect(self.cutContent)
        # Connect Help actions
        self.helpContentAction.triggered.connect(self.helpContent)
        self.aboutAction.triggered.connect(self.about)
    
        self.openRecentMenu.aboutToShow.connect(self.populateOpenRecent)


    def newFile(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>File > New</b> clicked")

    def openFile(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>File > Open...</b> clicked")

    def saveFile(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>File > Save</b> clicked")

    def copyContent(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>Edit > Copy</b> clicked")

    def pasteContent(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>Edit > Pate</b> clicked")

    def cutContent(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>Edit > Cut</b> clicked")

    def helpContent(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>Help > Help Content...</b> clicked")

    def about(self):
        self.label.setText("<b>Help > About...</b> clicked")

    def populateOpenRecent(self):
        self.openRecentMenu.clear()
        actions = []
        filenames = [f"File-{n}" for n in range(5)]
        for filename in filenames:
            action = QAction(filename, self)
            action.triggered.connect(partial(self.openRecentFile, filename))
            actions.append(action)
        self.openRecentMenu.addActions(actions)
        
    def openRecentFile(self, filename):
        self.label.setText(f"<b>{filename}</b> opened") 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, откуда у Вас столько времени на помощь? Вы как-будто работаете на stackoverflow помощником :D

Comment: @GunTHE пожалуйста. Нравится мне это.